# Remembering state in react through refreshes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a solution that will store `state` locally when refreshing the browser.

Our app has many translations with a language selector but currently upon a browser refresh this state is reset to the default.

Within the app, as authorised we save the chosen language to Firebase and `onMount` the chosen user language is shown, however, on our page without authentication, such as the login page and create page, this is not possible.

Currently, language is selected and stored as a state using `Context` as

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';

// Translations
import EN from '../../../constants/translations/en.json';
import TR from '../../../constants/translations/tr.json';
import ES from '../../../constants/translations/es.json';

interface InterfaceState {
  langCode?: string;
  translate?: any;
  dispatch: any;
}

const translations: any = {
  en: EN,
  tr: TR,
  es: ES
};

const getTranslate = (langCode: string) => (key: string | number) =>
  translations[langCode][key] || key;

const initialState = {
  langCode: 'en',
  translate: getTranslate('en'),
  dispatch: ''
};

export const I18nContext = React.createContext<InterfaceState>(initialState);

export const I18nContextProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const reducer = (state: any, action: { type: any; payload: any }) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'setLanguage':
        return {
          langCode: action.payload,
          translate: getTranslate(action.payload)
        };
      default:
        return { ...initialState };
    }
  };

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value = { ...state, dispatch };

  return <I18nContext.Provider value={value as any}>{children}</I18nContext.Provider>;
};
```

The language selector uses `useContext` to set state and this works fine until the user refreshes the browser and the default `langCode` is applied.

One solution I've tried that works but has required much to keep maintained, especially as it requires me to add additional steps to `Link` components, is to `history.push(pathname)` and add a string query with the `langCode` in a string as

```
const onLanguageSelect = (data: any) => {
  dispatch({ type: 'setLanguage', payload: data.value });
  history.push(location.pathname + `?lang=` + data.value);
};
```

My question, how can I store the chosen state to `session` or `local` storage? And is this a viable and scalable solution, especially across multiple domains as app.example.com and example.com?

Comment: maybe you should put your state into `localStorage`

Comment: I've looked into that but not finding a method to using `localStorage` across multiple domains.

Comment: What do you mean `multiple domains` ?

Comment: app.example.com and example.com

Comment: Whats about a Cookie?

Comment: That was where I was hoping an answer would put me. Unfortunately, I'm not too familiar with adding and reading cookies in React. Any direction to resources would be great.

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384

this can help

Comment: @DominikMatis. Thank you. That is exactly the type of resource I had been needing. Did you want to put in an answer to be accepted?

Comment: Sure, I will add it

Comment: You can also resolve to cookies (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) and handling cookies in react is no different than in any other JS application

Comment: Thank you @AdamKosmala. Another great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iframe` to share what you have saved in `localStorage`/`sessionStorage`

Here is the [link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384)

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I think local or session is not the option. As it is not saved across different subdomains. I think an option might be to use a cookie. Cookies can be shared with multiple sub domains without a problem.

Just save it in a cookie when you language is selected and fetch in in the default value of your context if it is defined.

Only downside is that some people have set their cookies off by default. So you might need to add a prompt that suggests the user to turn on their cookies for you application.

Comment: Default cookies handeling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/share-localstorage-sessionstorage-between-different-domains-eb07581e9384 with this, you can share `localStorage` across domains

Comment: Handy package if you want it a bit easier: https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie

Comment: @DominikMatis First implementation step use a iFrame... That's a bit tacky IMO.

Comment: Thank you Raoul. Great answer but it looks as if @DominikMatis has a solution the the cookies off problem.